# Try Catch not catching syntax error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with someone else's JavaScript file, and they declared a function like the following.

```
function window.confirm(str) {
..... code here .....
}
```

This works fine with IE, but in Google Chrome, it throws an uncaught syntax error on the period in `window.confirm`.  I tried to put a try catch around it like below, but that didn't work, same syntax error.  It then won't let me use any functions defined in that JavaScript file.

```
try {
    var window.confirm = function(str) {
        ..... code here .....
    };
}
catch(e) {}
```

I also tried to change the declaration to a variable, like below, but that didn't work either.  Same error.

```
var window.confirm = function(str) {
    ..... code here .....
};
```

Is there a way to catch this in Chrome?

Comment: Er... you can't catch syntax errors. How about fixing it instead? `window.confirm = function(str) {...};`

Comment: People aren't going to like me for pointing out that you *can* catch syntax errors if you parse the code with `eval()`. That would be a terrible idea in this case however because that **is** a syntax error and it should just be fixed.

Comment: @Pointy: Eh, I'd count that as "catching a `SyntaxError`" as opposed to "catching a syntax error".

Comment: @minitech Ha ha good point :-) It's not something I'd normally bring up but I've been working with a JavaScript templating system lately and now I have to deal with caught "SyntaxErrors" all the time.

Comment: @minitech - Thanks for the edit.  I know it was a syntax error, but I didn't know how to fix it.  It worked fine in IE which is why I was just trying to catch it for the other browsers so nothing broke.

everyoneelse - Thank for for the knowledge that try/catch only catches runtime, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Writing code that has a syntax error and parsing that through `eval()`, that's... crazy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function window.confirm(str)` and `var window.confirm ...` are invalid. instead, try:

```
window.confirm = function(str){
..... code here .....
}
```

Comment: This was the simple answer to what I was looking for.  It fixed the syntax error in Chrome.  The answers dealing with try/catch at execution time answer the other part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Two points :

- `try/catch` are used to detect execution errors, not compilation ones. Don't deploy code with syntax errors.
- `function window.confirm(){` is a MS idiom you must avoid. You may use `window.confirm = function() {` or, if you're in the global scope, simply `var confirm = function() {`.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need to try and catch "Uncaught SyntaxError" errors, then you'll have to rely on JavaScript's hidden-under-the-floorboard misunderstood stepchild `eval()` function.

In the sample code below, `obj` will only be updated if the incoming string evaluates to a valid object; otherwise `obj` will default to `{}`. Let's assume `$someTextField` pulls in settings entered in a CMS textarea field, and the content editor has entered this malformed string in the field:

```
{
  "foo": "bar
}
```

Sample code:

```
var oSettings = {};

// Returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)"
try {
  oSettings = <?php echo $someTextField ?>;
} catch(e) {}

// This works
try {
  eval('oSettings = <?php echo $someTextField ?>');
} catch(e) {}
```

Keep in mind that if the string to be evaluated is coming from some external source (e.g., CMS) and you have no control over it as in this example, then you'll need to do three things:

1. Detect and prevent execution of JavaScript code that could potentially wreck hell on your app.
2. Escape quotes in the incoming string to avoid conflicts with the JavaScript quotes. Since we're using PHP in this example, it would be better to do something like this:

   `eval('oSettings = <?php echo addslashes($someTextField) ?>');`
3. Remove line breaks since the evaluated string needs to be on one single line. It would be even better to do something like this:

   `eval('oSettings = <?php echo addslashes(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "", $someTextField)) ?>');`

Answer (score 1):

You must fix the syntax errors. Try/catch will not catch syntax errors because syntax errors are compile time errors and try/catch can only catch runtime errors.